# Setting connection reference to null after closing it

Tags: java, database-connection, connection-pooling

Is it required/good practice to set the connection reference to null after closing it?

I am closing connections in `finally` block.

```
conn.close();
conn = null;
```

I am facing connection wait timeout exception during performance testing 
as the maximum connections are getting exceeded.

Comment: Is this a local variable? A field? What do you *hope* to achieve here?

Comment: Maybe this helps you to identify what happend if i set an object to null: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009909/clearing-or-set-null-to-objects-in-java)

Comment: @Jon ..I m trying to find if there is any connection leakage in my code .. although all connections are being closed....at one point application run out of connections...I am using IBM Was 7

Comment: The Garbage Collector is going to removed it, don't need to put a `null` reference after you closed it.

Comment: If I set conn to null..Will this close the connection held by it or it will remain open....according to me that should get closed

Answer (score 0):

You'll see this pattern in use when people want to *explicitly* throw away a reference, and thus aid garbage collection, and trigger finalisers. This is virtually always redundant.

If the `conn` variable is used to indicate that a new connection is required (by making it a field, perhaps, and resetting it to `null` before later reference) then that's a different pattern, but unrelated to immediate resource management.